# I am getting an error called ImportError: no module named testapp in django

Tags: python, django

My project name is `practice` and my application name is `testapp`. This is my project structure:

```
django/bin/practice

\practice
      -practice folder
              -__init__.py
              -settings.py
              -urls.py
              -wsgi.py
      -testapp folder
              -migrations folder
              -templates folder
                        -index.html
              -__init__.py
              -admin.py
              -models.py
              -tests.py
              -views.py
      -manage.py
```

I have included my application name in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` but I am still getting this error:

`ImportError: no module named testapp in django`

[this is the error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQDUj.jpg)

```html
<pre>Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/

Django Version: 1.8.5
Python Version: 2.7.8
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'testapp')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  119.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  365.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  401.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  395.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\practice\practice\urls.py" in <module>
  22.     url(r'^practice/', include(testapp.views.home))

Exception Type: NameError at /
Exception Value: name 'testapp' is not defined</pre>
```

Comment: what is the command that you run.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post whole error message and other information that you think relevant so that we can help.

Comment: i have mentioned the  error at the end of  my post now . please see there..

Comment: thanks for your response

Comment: @surya Share the import line that triggers the error

Comment: i have updated my  error i am getting when i am trying to open my application created in my project

Comment: . i can't understand where the error is   so please help me @4140tm